# vb.net error -->Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

```
 Me.SqlConnection1.ConnectionString = dbconn.ConnectionString

    Me.SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * From repSMI where Date Between '" & formSMI.DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and '" & formSMI.DateTimePicker2.Value & "'"
    Dim DsetSMI1 As New DataSet
    Me.DsetSMI1.Clear()
    Me.SqlDataAdapter1.Fill(Me.DsetSMI1, "repSMI")


    Dim x As New repSMI
    x.SetDataSource(Me.DsetSMI1)
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = x
    Me.CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

what would be the possible fix for this? thanks!

Comment: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not opening your connection. And not assigning it to your command. Try adding

```
Me.SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = Me.SqlConnection1
Me.SqlConnection1.Open();
```

after

```
Me.SqlConnection1.ConnectionString = dbconn.ConnectionString
```

Don't forget to close it after DataSet is filled.

Comment: I realize this is answered but how do you speficy a parameter on this type of query?

Comment: OP has parameter as a part of query text, but this is not the best choice. `Me.SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand` has a `.Parameters` collection, so you can use `Me.SqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add( )` to add parameters. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection_methods.aspx